# Show two highest N numbers c#

Tags: c#, console, numbers, highest

I have a question, I want to know how i can show on CONSOLE the 2 highest of N entered numbers? Im doing something like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter the weight of the fish:");
if(decimal.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out _fishWeight))
{
    if (_fishWeight > _highest2)
    {
        _highest = _fishWeight;
        if (_fishWeight < _highest1)
        {
            _highest = _fishWeight;
        }
    }       
}
```

but it doesn't work. It only shows me the _highest1 but not the other _highest...

If someone can help me, I would be really glad!

Comment: You're setting `_highest` but comparing to `_highest2` and `_highest1` and the second one is doing less than, are those typos?  In any case you'll want to compare to whatever variable has the highest first and if it's higher set the second highest to the highest then the highest to the current value.  Then if it's not higher than the highest you compare to the second highest and set it accordingly.

Comment: Add them all to a List, sort it, display the first two numbers.

Comment: Next time use [step by step debugging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/getting-started-with-the-debugger) to check your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you want something more like

```
if (_fishweight > _highest)
{
    _highest2 = _highest;
    _highest = _fishweight;
}
else if(_fishweight > _highest2)
{
    _highest2 = _fishweight;
}
```

Alternatively If you want a more flexible leaderboard

```
// declare something like...

    private List<int> _leaderboard = new List<int>();
    private readonly int _leaderboardCount = 2;

// then update it like...    
    _leaderboard.Add(_fishweight);
    _leaderboard = _leaderboard.OrderByDescending(v => v).Take(_leaderboardCount).ToList();
```

Now you have the top 2,  but you can easily change it to a top 10 later on if you want.

Comment: Thanks Nicholas!! I've used the first formula and worked FLAWLESSLY. Thank you so much! :D

Answer (score 0):

`Math.Max()` is your friend here. No need to do manual comparison, just feed in two values, it'll output the highest of them and just set that to your `_heighestWeight`.

```
while (true)
{
    Console.Write("Enter the weight of the fish: ");
    var input = Console.ReadLine();
    if (decimal.TryParse(input, out _fishWeight))
    {
        break;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Please only enter a decimal number");
    Console.Clear();
}

_heighestWeight = Math.Max(_fishWeight, _heighestWeight);
```

I also added a `while` loop in case they input something other than a decimal.